# How to optimize storage and access of large 70000x70000 Tensors with minimal disk space and fast read time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, local-storage, bigdata

I've been working with some pretty large tensors (approximately 1000 tensors with shape 70000x70000) and I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to store and access them. I've tried using h5py and chunking the tensors into smaller pieces, but even that approach takes up too much storage space and takes a long time to read.

Here's a sample code I've been working with:

```py
import numpy as np
import h5py
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def pairwise_distances_chunks(X, chunk_size=1000):
    chunked_X = np.array_split(X, X.shape[0] // chunk_size + 1)
    for i, X_chunk in enumerate(chunked_X):
        dists = cdist(X_chunk, X, metric="euclidean")
        with h5py.File(f"cdist_chunk{i}.h5", "w") as f:
            f.create_dataset("cdist", data=dists)

train_vec = np.random.randn(70000, 1000)
pairwise_distances_chunks(train_vec[:, [0]])
with h5py.File("/content/cdist_chunk0.h5", "r") as f:
    dset = f["cdist"]
    dists = dset[:]
    print(dset[:100])
```

As you can see, I'm using h5py and chunking the tensors to save on storage space, but it's still taking a long time to read. I'm hoping there's a better solution out there that can reduce the storage space and increase the reading speed.

Do you have any suggestions or solutions to improve the storage and readability of large tensors? I'm looking for ways to reduce the amount of storage space required and increase the speed of reading.

P.S. I'm open to using alternative databases or programming languages, or any other techniques that may help solve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If those are 32-bit floats, you are talking about 20 TB of data.  There is no "efficient" way to store and access 20 TB of data.  It would take most of a day just to read that much data from a fast disk.  Honestly, what you need is a different algorithm that doesn't need so much data.